# convert ASCII into Hex

Tags: java, hex, ascii, data-conversion

I have a Gui where i want to convert ASCII into Hex, but it prints me fffff84 instead of 84. This only happens at ä, ö, ü. What went wrong?

Example input:

```
ä
```

Output:

```
ffffff84
```

My Code:

```
asciihex.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            output6.setText("");
            String hexadecimal2 = input4.getText().replace("\n", "");
            byte[] chars;
            try {
                chars = hexadecimal2.getBytes("CP850");
                StringBuffer hexa = new StringBuffer();
                for(int i = 0;i<chars.length;i++){
                    hexa.append(Integer.toHexString((int) chars[i]));
                }
                output6.append(hexa.toString());                    
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {

                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) is really a 7-bit encoding scheme (with values going from `0` to `127` (`0x7f`)). `0x84` might be part of [*extended* ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII) but is non-standard. It's also a *negative* number if stored in a signed byte (using [two's complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement)). Because it's negative, it gets a sign-extension if you store the signed byte in a larger signed integer type.

Comment: `CP850` is not `ASCII`.

Comment: [Code page 850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850) is not [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). And `ä` is not an ASCII character.

Comment: @saka1029 why isnt it ASCII?

Comment: @Starlight: For the same reason Spanish is not English, despite having some words in common. It just isn't. See the links in my comment above for details.

Comment: yeah and 84 = ä.

Comment: @Starlight: *"yeah and 84 = ä"* **Not in ASCII.** ASCII doesn't have the `ä` character. *Please* bother to read the linked articles.

Comment: @Starlight Use `US-ASCII`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Code page 850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850) is not [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). And `ä` is not an ASCII character. Neither are your other examples of characters that don't work correctly.

What's happening is that the values of those characters, as bytes, are negative, because `byte` is a signed type in Java. (`ä` is -124, for instance.) -124 in two's complement hex as an `int` is 0xFFFFF84. You can get the unsigned version of that by adding it to 256, to get 132 (0x84). Then your conversion to hex would work.

Comment: why is this not ASCII ? when i convert hex into ASCII i use E4 and it prints ä. So why doenst this work if i want to convert Ascii to Hex?

Comment: another way to convert `byte` to `int` ignoring the sign: `hexa.append(Integer.toHexString((int) chars[i] & 0xFF));`

Comment: @Starlight please read the ASCII articles on Wikipedia, it's just a click for you...

Comment: @T.J. Crowder how do i add 0xFFFFF84 to 256?

Comment: @Starlight: Um...`chars[0] < 0 ? chars[0] + 256 : chars[0]`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder in which line do i use this?

Comment: @Starlight: How about you try to work that out for yourself. But think: Where are you getting the invalid value? Where are you using `chars[i]`? (Not `chars[0]`, sorry.)

Answer (score 0):

You have to make an **unsigned conversion** of byte value to int, e.g.

```
hexa.append(Integer.toHexString((int) chars[i] & 0xFF));
```

or (Java 8)

```
hexa.append(Integer.toHexString(Byte.toUnsignedInt(chars[i])));
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, hexadecimal value of "ä" is not 0x84, its 0x7B.
For checking all the hexadecimal values please refer standard "ETSI TS 123 038 V14.0.0 (2017-04)".

Now for the coding part, I already made a function which takes any ASCII character and returns its hexadecimal value as per given standard. Since I do not want to post that code as it will be spoon feeding, instead I want to guide you to write your own.

Steps:
1. First refer the given document and understand the given character tables.
2. Create a list which contains the all the characters given in the table as per index values.
3. Make a function to extract the given character's index position and make the actual hexadecimal number. Do keep in mind to write extra functionality for extended character set.

Hope this will help you. :-)

Comment: *"First of all, hexadecimal value of "ä" is not 0x84, its 0x7B"* Not in code page 850. It's 0x84 in CP850. In other code pages, it'll have other values. It's [U-00E4](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=00E4) in Unicode.

Comment: Hi  T.J. Thank you for the comment. Now one thing that I want to mention is, if we are talking about hexadecimal values, then we have to refer ETSI TS 123 038 V14.0.0 (2017-04) because it is a standard for characters hexadecimal values. I am only talking about a generic standard and according to this standard, value is 0x7B. Please feel free to read this standard. :-)

Comment: A standard regarding cellular data transmission has exactly **zero** applicability here. Again: The numeric value representing the character varies based on the code page / text encoding. The OP is using the numeric value, rendered as hex. You may find [this article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) useful with regard to different encodings for the same characters.

Comment: Hi T.J. Thanks for making point but I understood correctly. I daily work on hexadecimal-text-hexadecimal conversions. OP has asked " i want to convert ASCII into Hex". There are different ways to convert the same but they could not be standard. The suggested conversion to 0x84 is incorrect as per given standard. I suggested the standard way of dealing hexadecimal values. Please tell me the standard for the code page conversion, it will be a new learning for me. :-)

Comment: Again, [this article](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) will probably be useful. And probably [this one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding) as well.

Comment: Hi T.J. Thanks for sending the links. I will surely read the same. :-)